# Apple App Store Subscriptions - Do they support quantity purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, licensing, subscription

I am in the process of writing an app that will require a subscription based payment model.

What I would like to know is does Apple's auto-renewing subscription API allow users to buy ***in quantity*** (i.e. I would like ten access codes to distribute to other devices) so the services I am offering can be accessed on other devices just by entering a generated key?

Example:

Admin downloads my app, tests it, and decides to deploy it to ten other devices. So the admin would buy ten subscriptions in the app using Apple's API. The app validates the purchases and generates ten keys for the admin to distribute to the other ten devices.

TIA :)

Comment: No, a subscription is made available to a single iTunes account. If that iTunes account is used on multiple devices then the subscription is available in all of those devices. I am developing an app with a similar business model. I track the number of devices running the app in my database and the user subscription enables a number of devices. If the number of active devices exceeds the subscribed amount then user either needs to remove inactive devices from the device list or uograde their subscription

Comment: Hadn't thought about that approach, thanks for your insight!